# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Tags: arrays, laravel, pluck

i know this is similar with other question, but.
how if we get the data array from db and try to compare those data ?

```
$x = Video::where('kursus_id', $data)->pluck('slug');
$z = Video::where('kelas_id', $data_id_kelas)
    ->where('mapel_id', $data_id_mapel)
    ->pluck('slug');

foreach ($z as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $x)) {
    
    } else {
         echo $value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

this throw me an error like `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`.

but when i try to change $x and $z with
$x=["2"]
$z=["1","2","3"]
Thats work. and output is 1 & 3
i think when i use db and give it pluck, this will became the same output when i use regular array like ["1","2","3"].

please correct me if my opinion goes wrong. cz im in study. Thanks before mates

Comment: they are not arrays they are Collections which are objects ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods  some of the available methods on the Collection class ... if you want the array from the Collections you can call `all()` on them

Comment: thanks for correction. and how to turn my data become an array  ?

Comment: but when i use all its turn like [{ data }] and object inside the array

Comment: when i use get all its turn like [[{ data }]]

Comment: how to transform my data become array like [ data ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) it 2nd param req. array and you are giving object that's why this error

to fix this you need to use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray) function in laravel

```php
$x = Video::where('kursus_id', $data)->pluck('slug')->toArray();
```

then you can use `in_array($value, $x)`